# Changing the Searched Location for google-services.json using complex flavour tree

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I know this has been asked already, but the problem persists for any version of com.google.gms:google-services above 4.2.0:
the searched location for my google-services.json file is no longer taking the flavour arborescence into consideration.

it only reads:

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

> Searched Location:
> ~/app/google-services.json

instead of **~/app/src/TopflavorSubflavor/release/google-services.json**

I have tried multiple permutations between the release folder and the flavor folder, even including Release in the flavor name, but nothing helps.

The official docs states it should work and that's why I am looking for something more than a workaround like creating the file in the /app/ folder at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to name your flavors with underscore lowercase or one-word lowercase names :

```
top_flavor 
subflavor
```

Comment: Where were you hiding all this time!! Thanks! Was I supposed to find the information somewhere in the official doc?

Comment: Nope. There were several issues on GitHub some time ago, and somewhere in those threads the answer was.